# Why is input size attribute allowed in HTML/XHTML Strict?

Tags: html, xhtml, standards, html-input

This passes validation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<form action="get">
<p><input type="text" size="10" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

as does the equivalent under HTML 4.01 Strict or XHTML 1.1.

The `size` attribute seems purely presentational to me.  So why have the W3C left it in the strict flavours of (X)HTML?

Answer (score 0):

There is no longer (officially) a "strict" version of HTML. There are however two different parsers: the HTML parser (loose) and the XML parser (strict). To make browsers use the XML parser use the following PHP code:

```
<?php
if (stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'],'application/xhtml+xml'))
{
 $mime = 'application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8';
}
else {$mime = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8';}//Unless IE6 or lower
//IE6 or lower should only use 'text/html'.
header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
?>
```

I believe that either this part was overseen back in the early late 1990s or early 2000s *or* if it wasn't likely the `size` attribute was perceived as being the size of the text and not the number of pixels that the `input` element should have been rendered as. It is also possible that if it wasn't overlooked it may have been for the purposes of backwards compatibility (some browsers may not have worked without the `size` attribute).

If you're looking to maximize your ability to code client side code I highly recommend moving to XHTML5. That is in more detail HTML5 rendered using the XML parser. The website in my profile is a live environment that demonstrate *much* if not all that you'd want to know to skip the greener mistakes if you're still deep in the learning process.

---

Yes, the `size` attribute changes the width of the `input` element and is presentational in nature. The problem in trying to validate it as necessary or that we should keep it is that if you set the `size` to `3` and type the letter l (as in **l**etter) you'll clearly see more of that letter than the `size` is set to. Only monospace fonts have a shared set width between all characters (l and w in example) and that can be achieved with CSS. In fact there are lots of `line-height` issues with fonts though less relevant here. Likely in my opinion, the reason that the `size` attribute exists in even [HTML 5.2 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-input-size) is that it likely has been over-looked. I'm not sure if W3C standards authors are paid through the W3C or not (most open source software developers are not paid in example) or perhaps since it's a likely well supported (and likely fairly well used attribute) people decided to keep it. At the end of the day I'd advise against it's use as it objectively serves no purpose competently.

Comment: Just realised I hadn't replied to this.  Firstly, what has what parser _browsers_ use to do with anything?  I am talking about validity/validation here.

Secondly, OK, so XHTML 1.0 Strict may no longer be official, but I wouldn't have thought this makes a difference to either the fact that it exists or how software (including both browsers and validators) should handle data declared as XHTML 1.0 Strict if it chooses to support the type.

Comment: @Stewart I added the last paragraph. Let me know if I omited anything.

Comment: Hmm.  You say "perhaps since it's a likely well supported (and likely fairly well used attribute)" but the same must have been true of (e.g.) `<font>`.

Furthermore, going by how `size` is defined, I suppose what browsers *should* be doing is rendering at that number of times the width of the widest character in the font being used.  But it doesn't look like that's what's happening.

Comment: And how do you mean it can be achieved with CSS but only with monospace fonts?  Is there a CSS unit that is defined the same as the unit of `size` when using a monospace font but isn't defined the same when using a proportional font?

Comment: @Stewart Monospaced fonts use the exact same width for every single character; everything else (AFAIK) use width specific to the character used. The browsers don't try to adjust because nothing has even been typed initially and even if they were there are much *much* higher priorities for the developers to focus on. This sort of code was likely implemented during the time when Microsoft was monopolizing the Internet with Internet Explorer and on top of that the people who were making actual progress on browsers were focused on improving CSS support.

Comment: I'll rephrase that.  You said, "Only monospace fonts have a shared set width between all characters (l and w in example) and that can be achieved with CSS."  How would you write `<input type="text" size="12" />` using CSS instead of a size attribute?

Comment: @Stewart First use `input {font-family: monospace;}`, secondly type a single character in the `input` element and select it, take a screenshot, paste it in Paint or whatever and crop the image to determine it's width. This is the closest you're going to get to controlling the set width of characters and the moment you change the `font-size` is the moment you're going to have to redo this. It's a hopeless pursuit and as someone who has built many incredible things to go completely unnoticed by even highly technically capable people my advice is accept no one is going to notice.

Comment: Then you're not really doing the same in CSS - by the sounds of it you're determining the equivalent width in pixels at some absolute font size.  A better approach would be to measure the aspect ratio of the character cell and then specify the width in ems.  But if you're using a proportional font, it goes without saying that you aren't going to try to size it just right to show a set number of characters at a time.

Comment: I'm really not interested in having an in-depth conversation about this topic and definitely not in the comments. To *answer your question* the `size` attribute is a miscellaneous relic from a time past that no one gave any serious consideration from when it came to deprecation as it is simply something that can/should be replaced with CSS and that is if someone even feels it's worthwhile to keep.